# What does TypeError, __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response' mean in python?

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm following the graphql python tutorial at https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/4-authentication/. It worked fine for the first 3 sections, but in the Authentication section I've run into this problem.

I am learning python, don't know Django or graphql, so it's a lot to digest all at once, but it was going ok until now. Also not sure what relevant bits to include here.

I followed all the instructions. When I go to my local project site at `localhost:8000/graphql/`, I get

`TypeError at /graphql/`
`__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'`

Here is the relevant snippet of my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
]

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'hackernews.schema.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': ['graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware', ],
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

I also did import graphql_jwt in my main schema.py

Here is some kind of stack trace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/graphql/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'graphene_django',
 'links']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  62.             self = cls(**initkwargs)

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\graphene_django\views.py" in __init__
  88.             self.middleware = list(instantiate_middleware(middleware))

File "C:\Users\e79909\projects\python\graphql-python\venv\lib\site-packages\graphene_django\views.py" in instantiate_middleware
  48.             yield middleware()

Exception Type: TypeError at /graphql/
Exception Value: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Insomnia is not even part of my issue. Once the settings are updated according to the tutorial, I can not open the GraphiQL interface anymore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I just found it.

```py
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'hackernews.schema.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARES': ['graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware'],
}
```

Notice the `S`. It needs to be `'MIDDLEWARES'`, not `'MIDDLEWARE'`.

Found the solution on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/issues/956)

Also, according to [this comment](https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/issues/956#issuecomment-496595362) on the same issue, you should add `'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware'` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list (the one with all the Django middleware).

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware', ### <---Add this line
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: I upvoted because this answer ultimately solved my issue, but I had to make some changes. Here is what worked for me: Under GRAPHENE = {} in settings use "MIDDLEWARE" (without the S). When I added both graphql_jwt middlwares to GRAPHENE and MIDDLEWARE I got an error saying to add the graphql_jwt middleware to GRAPHENE['MIDDLEWARE'] and to remove it from Django middleware classes.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade django-graphql-jwt to 0.3.4 (or higher) from the tutorial's 0.1.5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the solution that actually worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue when we moved from Django 2.2 to Django 4.0.5 version.
Updated the DRF version from 3.12.0 to 3.14.0 to fix this issue.

pip install djangorestframework==3.14.0